# Email forwarding via spf record

Tags: email, spf

I have old-domain.co.il with several emails and a new-domain.co.il with the same email addresses.

I don't want to connect my domain to a server via mx to make that transfer via email server.
Is it possible to have a SPF record that get an email like user@old-domail.co.il and transfer it to user@new-domain.co.il?

The new domain is on google apps and the old domain can be connected to the same apps, but how to do it, so emails will arrive only to the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of SPF records entirely. SPF records are used to help receiving mail servers (better) know if the email it receives is coming from an IP address the sender has specified is legitimate.

In no way do SPF records help receiving email servers forward mail from 1 domain to another.

You should look into Dual Delivery if you're worried about losing mail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SPF records to redirect emails from one domain to another (as David W rightly pointed out)

You're best bet would be to use email forwarding/redirection.

You mention that you are using GoogleApps to handle the mail for the new domain, if you link the old domain to the same account you can setup the forwarding/redirection there. Take a look under the "Domain Settings" pages in the master control panel. This will only apply to new emails received however. If you want to have existing emails from the old mailboxes in the new ones, you can "Allow users to upload mail using the Email Migration API." under settings>email in the GoogleApps Control Panel to allow importing of the old emails to GoogleApps.